# SSRS Convert date and groupby

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008

I have a DateTime type column called `CreatedDate` in my SQL table, and I have created a report using SSRS 2008.

I have grouped my table in my report with this `CreatedDate`.

I need to orderby this `CreatedDate` in the format of `dd/MM/yyyy`.

If I convert this column value as `Convert(varchar(10),CreateDate,101)` am getting the values in the format of `MM/dd/yyyy` and its sorting the datas correctly like,

```
03/03/2012
03/05/2012
05/03/2012
```

The same way If I convert the column as `Convert(varchar(10),CreatedDate,103)` am getting the values in the format of `dd/MM/yyyy` and its sorting like

```
03/03/2012
04/05/2012
05/03/2012
```

but I need to group the table like

```
03/03/2012
05/03/2012
04/05/2012
```

like this, for this I tried giving the sort function in the tablix manually like

```
=Format(Fields!CreatedDate.value,"dd/MM/yyyy")
```

but its not working, how can I fix this....can anyone help me here...

the query am using here is

```
SELECT ItemName
       , COUNT(ItemName) AS Quantity
       , SUM(LineTotal) AS Amount
       , CONVERT(varchar(10), CreatedDate, 103) AS CreatedDate
FROM StudentFeesItems
WHERE (CONVERT(varchar(10), CreatedDate, 101) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
GROUP BY ItemName, CreatedDate
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the date on those 2 formats on the dataset and then sort by one of them:

```
SELECT [YourColumns], Convert(varchar(8),CreateDate,112) SortDate,
       Convert(varchar(10),CreatedDate,103) Displaydate
FROM YourTable
```

This way, you can use `DisplayDate` on your tablix and sort manually by `SortDate`.

Comment: great idea, I tried but still am getting the same order(incorrect)

Comment: @Shanish - I changed the `convert` for `SortDate`, try again and let me know if it helps

Comment: thanks Lamak for ur kind response, its not working, am still getting the incorrect order

Comment: @Shanish - Are you sure that you are configuring correctly the sort property on your tablix or group?

Comment: am sure i've configured it correctly, anyhow will check it once again

Answer (score 2):

Don't convert your date to strings.  Keep them as dates and sort them as dates.

As you've already experienced, unless you have the string formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD` you won't get the order that you want.  If you keep the date as a DATETIME datatype, you can order by it, group by it, format it and do what you like to it.

```
DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CreateDate), 0) AS roundedDate
```

**RE-EDIT**

Here is my suggestion in your query...

```
WITH
  main_query
AS
(
  SELECT
    ItemName,
    DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CreatedDate), 0) AS CreatedDate,
    COUNT(ItemName) AS Quantity,
    SUM(LineTotal) AS Amount
  FROM
    StudentFeesItems
  WHERE
        CreatedDate >= @StartDate
    AND CreatedDate <  DATEADD(DAY, 1, @EndDate)
  GROUP BY
    ItemName,
    DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CreatedDate), 0)
)
SELECT
  ItemName,
  Convert(varchar(10), CreatedDate, 103)    AS formattedDate,
  Quantity,
  Amount
FROM
  main_query
ORDER BY
  ItemName,
  CreatedDate
```

Notes:
- Don't call a function on a field and THEN filter it
- Don't use string manilpulation to round a datetime to a date
- Don't sort by the string representation of dates

Comment: but I need to dispaly the date in the format of dd/MM/yyyy, thats what am trying, its sorting perfectly if it is in the format of MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: @Shanish - Only if all the dates are in the same year.  Could you include your code so we can comment on it directly?  In the mean time I've added a generic example to the answer.

Comment: thanks for ur response Dems, kindly check my updated question

Answer (score 2):

how about adding a `ROW_NUMBER() over (order by CreatedDate) as myOrder`  on your sql query and order by myOrder?

EDIT:

```
=Format(Fields!date.Value,"dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Comment: I tried using the order by clause in my query, since am using the CreatedDate in the group by of my table its not working, it sorts in its own order

Comment: didn't get it. If the date is in your group by, why cant you order by it?

Comment: of course I can order by it, if its in the format of "MM/dd/yyyy" its coming correctly, but I want it to be "dd/MM/yyyy"

Comment: am getting the same order as I mentioned in my question(my first example)